# How to change labels of a BatchDataset created with image_dataset_from_directory?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, dataset, label

I have a folder with categorized images in subfolders, and I'm using image_dataset_from_directory to create a BatchDataset. The categories are actually related to measurements, so each label represents a float value. How do I convert the labels in the BatchDataset to floats so I can use a regression style model with the data?